# Java read windows shared folder path from properties file

Tags: java, windows

In a Java SE application, I am trying to read path of a shared folder in windows OS. the path for shared folder is -  `\\MyMachineName\SharedFolder`

Now the problem is I need to make this path configurable. as it may change frequently. So I have kept this in a properties file. but when I read it, it becomes `\MyMachineNameSharedFolder`.

**Is there any way I can solve this without using double slash in properties file?**

Comment: Try to use `\\\\MyMachineName\\SharedFolder` if using backslashes is not a huge obstacle

Comment: yes I know I can do that. but the requirement is I need to put the exact shared path. I have mentioned in my question as well.

Comment: Then do not use a `property` file for storing this option. Read it as text (from txt file for example)

Comment: `String s = "\\MyMachineName\SharedFolder";` won't even compile!

Comment: That's because backslash has special meaning in java. It escapes the following symbol so that together they represent one special symbol and there is no such a sequence as `\S`. You have to double the backslash in java strings in order to get one backslash in place.